# ARToolkit libraries missing

Tags: artoolkit

So I've attempted to set up ARToolkit for my Win7 64-bit computer.
I'm using "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop".

I followed these instructions:

```
1. Unpack the ARToolKit zip to a convenient location. This location will be referred to below as {ARToolKit}.
2. Unpack the DSVideoLib zip into {ARToolKit}. Make sure that the directory is named "DSVL".
3. Copy the files DSVL.dll and DSVLd.dll from {ARToolKit}\DSVL\bin into {ARToolKit}\bin.
4. Install the GLUT DLL into the Windows System32 folder, and the library and headers into the VS platform SDK folders.
5. Run the script {ARToolKit}\Configure.win32.bat to create include/AR/config.h.
6. Open the ARToolKit.sln file (VS.NET) or ARToolkit.dsw file (VS6).
7. Build the toolkit.
```

The VRML renderering library and example (libARvrml & simpleVRML) are optional builds:

```
1. Unpack the OpenVRML zip into {ARToolKit}.
2. Copy js32.dll from {ARToolKit}\OpenVRML\bin into {ARToolKit}\bin.
3.Enable the libARvrml and simpleVRML projects in the VS configuration manager and build.
```

But at step 7, when I try to build the toolkit, an error saying

"Unable to start program 'C:\Users.....\ARToolKit\lib\SRC\AR\Debug\libAR.lib'.
The system cannot find the file specified.

I checked the \lib\SRC\ folder, and all the sources in there did not have a .lib file.

I'm guessing this shouldn't happen. Am I supposed to create the files, or is there a way around this? Is this because of incompatibility?

Comment: Which version of ARToolKit?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio-- project explorer: right click on "simpleTest" and set as startup project.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean solution and try again, if this doesn't work, try compiling project by project, yes, this will take ages, but this way you'll find the project that is giving you trouble!